# Python SIEM log collector hangs randomly

Tags: python, rest, syslog

I am trying to troubleshoot a script for Mimecast's API. The script runs fine for the most part, but a few times, I have noticed that it stops pulling logs and generally appears to be a hung process. After restarting the script and manually pushing logs to the syslog server, it starts working again without issue. I am not able to reproduce this issue at will.

The script is supposed to do the following:

1. Authenticate against Mimecast's API
2. Sign responses
3. download, extract and save log files to log dir
4. utilize a tokenized header to determine which file was downloaded in the last request. Should save the token ID within a file in the checkpoint directory
5. Push files to remote syslog server
6. Output any errors and info to console

Below is the sample code from Mimecast.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging.handlers
import json
import os
import requests
import base64
import uuid
import datetime
import hashlib
import shutil
import hmac
import time
from zipfile import ZipFile
import io
 
# Set up variables
APP_ID = "YOUR DEVELOPER APPLICATION ID"
APP_KEY = "YOUR DEVELOPER APPLICATION KEY"
URI = "/api/audit/get-siem-logs"
EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOUR ADMINISTRATOR'
ACCESS_KEY = 'ACCESS KEY FOR YOUR ADMINISTRATOR'
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET KEY FOR YOUR ADMINISTRATOR'
LOG_FILE_PATH = "FULLY QUALIFIED PATH TO FOLDER TO WRITE LOGS"
CHK_POINT_DIR = 'FULLY QUALIFIED PATH TO FOLDER TO WRITE PAGE TOKEN'
 
# Set True to output to syslog, false to only save to file
syslog_output = False
# Enter the IP address or hostname of your syslog server
syslog_server = 'localhost'
# Change this to override default port
syslog_port = 514
# delete files after fetching
delete_files = True
# Set threshold in number of files in log file directory
log_file_threshold = 10000
 
# Set up logging (in this case to terminal)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s')
log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
log.addHandler(log_handler)
 
# Set up syslog output
syslog_handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(syslog_server, syslog_port))
syslog_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
syslog_handler.setFormatter(syslog_formatter)
syslogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
syslogger = logging.getLogger('SysLogger')
syslogger.addHandler(syslog_handler)
 
 
# Supporting methods
def get_hdr_date():
    return datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S UTC")
 
 
def read_file(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
 
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Error reading file ' + file_name + '. Cannot continue. Exception: ' + str(e))
        quit()
 
 
def write_file(file_name, data_to_write):
    if '.zip' in file_name:
        try:
            byte_content = io.BytesIO(data_to_write)
            zip_file = ZipFile(byte_content)
            zip_file.extractall(LOG_FILE_PATH)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Error writing file ' + file_name + '. Cannot continue. Exception: ' + str(e))
            quit()
 
    else:
        try:
            with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
                f.write(data_to_write)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Error writing file ' + file_name + '. Cannot continue. Exception: ' + str(e))
            quit()
 
 
def get_base_url(email_address):
    # Create post body for request
    post_body = dict()
    post_body['data'] = [{}]
    post_body['data'][0]['emailAddress'] = email_address
 
    # Create variables required for request headers
    request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request_date = get_hdr_date()
    headers = {'x-mc-app-id': APP_ID, 'x-mc-req-id': request_id, 'x-mc-date': request_date}
 
    # Send request to API
    log.debug('Sending request to https://api.mimecast.com/api/discover-authentication with request Id: ' +
                  request_id)
    try:
        r = requests.post(url='https://api.mimecast.com/api/login/discover-authentication',
                          data=json.dumps(post_body), headers=headers)
        # Handle Rate Limiting
        if r.status_code == 429:
            log.warning('Rate limit hit. sleeping for ' + str(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] * 1000))
            time.sleep(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] * 1000)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Unexpected error getting base url. Cannot continue.' + str(e))
        quit()
 
    # Handle error from API
    if r.status_code != 200:
        log.error('Request returned with status code: ' + str(r.status_code) + ', response body: ' +
                      r.text + '. Cannot continue.')
        quit()
 
    # Load response body as JSON
    resp_data = json.loads(r.text)
 
    # Look for api key in region region object to get base url
    if 'region' in resp_data["data"][0]:
        base_url = resp_data["data"][0]["region"]["api"].split('//')
        base_url = base_url[1]
    else:
        # Handle no region found, likely the email address was entered incorrectly
        log.error(
            'No region information returned from API, please check the email address.'
            'Cannot continue')
        quit()
 
    return base_url
 
 
def post_request(base_url, uri, post_body, access_key, secret_key):
 
    # Create variables required for request headers
    request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request_date = get_hdr_date()
 
    unsigned_auth_header = '{date}:{req_id}:{uri}:{app_key}'.format(
        date=request_date,
        req_id=request_id,
        uri=uri,
        app_key=APP_KEY
    )
    hmac_sha1 = hmac.new(
        base64.b64decode(secret_key),
        unsigned_auth_header.encode(),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest()
    sig = base64.encodebytes(hmac_sha1).rstrip()
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'MC ' + access_key + ':' + sig.decode(),
        'x-mc-app-id': APP_ID,
        'x-mc-date': request_date,
        'x-mc-req-id': request_id,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 
    try:
        # Send request to API
        log.debug('Sending request to https://' + base_url + uri + ' with request Id: ' + request_id)
        r = requests.post(url='https://' + base_url + uri, data=json.dumps(post_body), headers=headers)
 
        # Handle Rate Limiting
        if r.status_code == 429:
            log.warning('Rate limit hit. sleeping for ' + str(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] * 1000))
            time.sleep(r.headers['X-RateLimit-Reset'] * 1000)
            r = requests.post(url='https://' + base_url + uri, data=json.dumps(post_body), headers=headers)
 
    # Handle errors
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Unexpected error connecting to API. Exception: ' + str(e))
        return 'error'
    # Handle errors from API
    if r.status_code != 200:
        log.error('Request to ' + uri + ' with , request id: ' + request_id + ' returned with status code: ' +
                      str(r.status_code) + ', response body: ' + r.text)
        return 'error'
 
    # Return response body and response headers
    return r.content, r.headers
 
 
def get_mta_siem_logs(checkpoint_dir, base_url, access_key, secret_key):
    uri = "/api/audit/get-siem-logs"
 
    # Set checkpoint file name to store page token
    checkpoint_filename = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'get_mta_siem_logs_checkpoint')
 
    # Build post body for request
    post_body = dict()
    post_body['data'] = [{}]
    post_body['data'][0]['type'] = 'MTA'
    post_body['data'][0]['compress'] = True
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_filename):
        post_body['data'][0]['token'] = read_file(checkpoint_filename)
 
    # Send request to API
    resp = post_request(base_url, uri, post_body, access_key, secret_key)
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
 
    # Process response
    if resp != 'error':
        resp_body = resp[0]
        resp_headers = resp[1]
        content_type = resp_headers['Content-Type']
 
        # End if response is JSON as there is no log file to download
        if content_type == 'application/json':
            log.info('No more logs available')
            return False
        # Process log file
        elif content_type == 'application/octet-stream':
            file_name = resp_headers['Content-Disposition'].split('=\"')
            file_name = file_name[1][:-1]
 
            # Save files to LOG_FILE_PATH
            write_file(os.path.join(LOG_FILE_PATH, file_name), resp_body)
            # Save mc-siem-token page token to check point directory
            write_file(checkpoint_filename, resp_headers['mc-siem-token'])
 
            try:
                if syslog_output is True:
                    for filename in os.listdir(LOG_FILE_PATH):
                        file_creation_time = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(LOG_FILE_PATH + "/" + filename))
                        if now < file_creation_time or now == file_creation_time:
                            log.info('Loading file: ' + filename + ' to output to ' + syslog_server + ':' + str(syslog_port))
                            with open(file=os.path.join(LOG_FILE_PATH, filename), mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as log_file:
                                lines = log_file.read().splitlines()
                                for line in lines:
                                    syslogger.info(line)
                            log.info('Syslog output completed for file ' + filename)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error('Unexpected error writing to syslog. Exception: ' + str(e))
            # return true to continue loop
            return True
        else:
            # Handle errors
            log.error('Unexpected response')
            for header in resp_headers:
                log.error(header)
            return False
 
 
def run_script():
    # discover base URL
    try:
        base_url = get_base_url(email_address=EMAIL_ADDRESS)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Error discovering base url for ' + EMAIL_ADDRESS + ' . Exception: ' + str(e))
        quit()
 
    # Request log data in a loop until there are no more logs to collect
    try:
        log.info('Getting MTA log data')
        while get_mta_siem_logs(checkpoint_dir=CHK_POINT_DIR, base_url=base_url, access_key=ACCESS_KEY,
                                secret_key=SECRET_KEY) is True:
            log.info('Getting more MTA log files')
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Unexpected error getting MTA logs ' + (str(e)))
    file_number = len([name for name in os.listdir(LOG_FILE_PATH) if os.path.isfile(name)])
    if delete_files or file_number >= log_file_threshold:
        for filename in os.listdir(LOG_FILE_PATH):
            file_path = os.path.join(LOG_FILE_PATH, filename)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                    os.unlink(file_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                    shutil.rmtree(file_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Failed to delete %s. Reason: %s' % (file_path, e))
    quit()
 
 
# Run script
run_script()
```

It seems like it may potentially be a race condition but I am not sure how to confirm since I can't reproduce it. I notice that SumoLogic has a modified version of this script as well with a different methodology for managing the files/paths. If this script works better than the main sample script above, would anybody be able to explain WHY? I haven't had any issues with it yet.

https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-content/blob/master/MimeCast/SumoLogic-Mimecast-Data-Collection/siem_collection.py

Comment: Is that fixing paid ?

Comment: Somewhat. The team that made the script doesn't intend it to be production grade code...but I have a few clients who utilize it in that capacity anyways. Im moreso curious of how those two sets of code differ in functionality when resolving those file paths and if it would be more optimal since I'm a noob with Python